# android Place Autocomplete how to get list of searched place on top by default

Tags: android, autocomplete, android-edittext, android-search

I implement place autocomplete in my application and write search keyword in `EditText` to get result according to search place keyword.
here the code for start PlaceAutocomplete activity to search place

```
int PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
try {
Intent intent =
        new 
 PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_FULLSCREEN)
                .build(this);
startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);
} catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
} catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
}
```

when activity launch list showing blank.

[image]

What I want-
already searched place should be show when activity launch like uber app

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to persistent your autocomplete results within internal app storage (shared preferences, database..) or somewhere you want. Basically, you need to implement your UI yourself. I don't  think you can customise the `PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder` for your needs.

1. Implement API-Call for AutocompleteGooglePlaces (we are using retrofit for this)

   ```
   @GET("/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json")
   Call<GoogleAutocompleteResponse> getAutoCompleteSearchResults(@Query("key") String apiKey,
             @Query("input") String searchTerm,
             @Query("location") String location,
             @Query("radius") long radius);
   ```
2. Perform call (on Enter-click or onTextChange)

   ```
   public List<GooglePlaceAutocompleteGeoModel> getAutoCompleteSearchResults(String searchTerm, LatLng center, long radius) {

      Call<GoogleAutocompleteResponse> call = googlePlacesRestApiService.getAutoCompleteSearchResults(API_KEY, searchTerm, getLocationStringFrom(center), radius);

       try {
           GoogleAutocompleteResponse autocompleteResponse = call.execute().body();
          List<GooglePlaceAutocompleteGeoModel> autocompleteResponsePredictions = autocompleteResponse.getPredictions();
          //Here are your Autocomplete Objects
          return autocompleteResponsePredictions;

      } catch (IOException e) {
          L.e("Error on Google Autocomplete call: " + e.getMessage());
      }

      return new ArrayList<>();
      }
   ```
3. Persistent the result of autocomplete result `GoogleAutocompleteResponse` within your app and implement logic for showing results in UI or populated within ListView

Comment: i can customize places autocomplete but i want native google places code

Comment: there is no "native google place" code for this behaviour. you have to implement it yourself. happy coding ;)

Comment: You may use GeoDataApi.getAutocompletePredictions() [ https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete#get_place_predictions_programmatically] for having native Android API

Comment: @longilong: Could you please paste this method getLocationStringFrom(center)

Comment: @ManoharPerepa: No. Read the API docs where you'll immediately find that this is a required `Google Place API` parameter. 

`location` — The latitude/longitude around which to retrieve place information. This must be specified as latitude,longitude.